# How to locate the corresponding commit in vscode repo to a monaco-editor-core release

Tags: monaco-editor

How to map a specific version of `monaco-editor-core` back to its git commit in vscode repo? I want to read the source code from which the release is built.

Background: I had some trouble implementing my own language support for monaco editor, need to check the source code. `/esm/` source code in the npm package is fine, but typescript source code is way better. But need to locate the correct git commit first, the vscode repo change so rapidly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1293

The copyright header of files in `/min` folder contain the commit:

```
/*!-----------------------------------------------------------
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Version: 0.15.5(3d42593a5844407ab71d47b348ea3a8de5fec848)
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
 *-----------------------------------------------------------*/
```